# Control on/off button on remote though Raspberry Pi

Tags: remote

Would it be possible to control the on/off button on the remote control shown on the image through my RPi? The remote is controlling a fan in my house, but i want to programme specific times during the day it should turn on.

Can I solder a wire directly between RPI and on/off button on the board or do I need something between? [image]

Comment: a relay would work ... an opto-coupler should work

Comment: I do something like this with an esp32 or rp2040 or arduino connected to a IR LED.  Recorded the output from the remote and just play that back on the LED.

Comment: Thats a clever solution @user10489, I will try that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may be possible to do this with a pi, it is even easier to do it with an Arduino class device.  (esp32 family, rp2040, arduino, etc.)

The point is to record the IR pulse stream from the remote, and then use the real time capabilities of the cpu to replay that stream on an IR LED.  There are multiple projects and tutorials published where people did similar things.

Note that the IR signal is usually a modulated pulse stream, where both the frequency of the LED and the frequency of the modulation are important and slightly standardized, but the pulse stream pattern is not standardized and different for every manufacturer.  (The modulation helps differentiate between random natural steady IR noise sources and remotes.)

Since there is some slight standardization, you can buy purpose built LEDs (and IR receivers) of the correct frequency with a built in modulation so all your cpu has to handle is the pulse stream.

Answer (score 0):

##### *"Would it be possible to ... ?"*

Yes - of course it's possible. But you'll need more information than what you've supplied in these photographs.